# How to create docker machine with OS Type: Windows?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-machine

When I create docker machine by following [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/), it creates **linux** host from `boot2docker.iso` image, with default OS Type: Linux.

How to specify OS Type as command parameter?

Something like this:

`docker-machine create --os-type windows`

P.S. Working OS is Windows 10 1703 with enabled Hyper-V

Comment: I don't think there is such a functionality available

Comment: What if we run `windowscore` in hyperv, install docker engine inside and connect from `docker-engine env host-machine-name` ? Why this not impossible do automatically?

Comment: Technically possible but you won't know what fails until you try